# Bookshelfjs - update related collection

Tags: bookshelf.js, knex.js

How can I update a related collection 
For eg:, I have the following models and collection

```
const Book = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'book',
    pages: function() {
        return this.hasMany(Page, 'book_id');
    }
});

const Page = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'page',
    idAttribute: 'page_id'
});

const Pages = bookshelf.Collection.extend({
    model: Page
});

function updateBook(){
    var book_id = 1;
    var book = {name: 'book1'};
    var pages = [{page_id: 1, book_id: 1, name: 'New Page 1'}, {page_id: 3, book_id: 1, name: 'Page 3'}];
    Book.forge({'book_id': book_id})
    .save(book)
    .then((newBook) => {
        /*
        **Here I want to update the pages of the book. **
        */
    });
}
```

Need to update pages in the following manner:
Assume the book had 2 pages initially:

```
[{page_id: 1, book_id: 1, name: 'Page 1'}, {page_id: 2, book_id: 1, name: 'Page 2'}]});
```

I want to:

1. Modify name of first page to 'New Page 1'
2. Delete page 2
3. Add a new Page 3

I tried the following, but no changes in page table.

```
newBook.load('pages')
    .then((newBook) =>{
        newBook.related('pages').reset(pages);
    })
```